# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient'

Tags: asp.net-core

I have migrate my Web project from RC1 to RC2, but I'm having this error:

> Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient' while attempting to
>   activate
>   'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.ExceptionTrackingMiddleware'.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add `"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final"` to your `project.json` and this to your `Startup` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
        ...
        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();
        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

        ...
        app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: What is "localizationOptions" here?

Comment: It's `RequestLocalizationOptions`, but not relevant to the question. I'll remove it.

Comment: UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry() and UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry() are no more needed and they are marked as obsolete.

Comment: do we need to do this in azure functions?

Comment: @AlexGordon - No