# invalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient'

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I am working with ASP.NET Core 3.1.

I have error in my browser, the browser can't load a referenced javascript file.

The browser console shows warning like below example

> "DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
> http://localhost:5000/app-assets/vendors/js/bootstrap.min.js.map: HTTP
> error: status code 500, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE"
>
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient' while attempting to
> activate 'Web.Features.Controllers.ErrorController'.
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
> sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIBnC.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923313/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-microsoft-applicationinsights-telemetryclien